# RSA Encryption and decryption incorrect with large message

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I recently got interested in RSA and tried to implement it.
This is a simplified version of my code:

```
def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, x, y = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, y - (b // a) * x, x)

def modinv(b, n):
    g, x, _ = egcd(b, n)
    if g == 1:
        return x % n

p = 89
q = 107
n = p * q
phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
e = 3
d = modinv(e, phi)

message = 74
encrypted = (message**e) % n
decrypted = (encrypted**d) % n

print(message)
print(encrypted)
print(decrypted)
```

For small of message, 74 is used in this example, it works fine.
However, when setting `message = 120000` or any other large value, the result is as follows:

```
120000
147
5724
```

So, I entered the exact same values into an RSA calculator on [this website](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~jpopyack/IntroCS/HW/RSAWorksheet.html).
This also resulted in an incorrectly decrypted message.

What could be the problem here? Is there a problem with the maths or is this a python problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It all works modulo `n`, so only "messages" in the range `0` through `n-1` inclusive can possibly work.  For you, `n = 89 * 107 = 9523`, so it's impossible that any "message" greater than 9522 can be recovered.

Comment: Thank you! So picking larger values for p and q allows for decrypting larger messages.

Comment: Yes - although the real point to larger `n` is to make `n` (which is part of the public key! it's not a secret) harder to factor.  Any `n` can be used to send a message of any size - just view a large message as, e.g., being an integer in base `n`, and encrypt one "digit" at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSA works modulo n. Therefore, messages cannot be more than or equal to n. This can be fixed by increasing the size of the prime numbers p and q. An easy way to generate large prime numbers is with the rabin-miller primality test. You can read more about that test here [Rabin-Miller Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

Also, on a side note, in your code you have

```
(message ** e) % n
```

whilst this is fast for small values, it is much faster to use the built in `pow` function

```
pow(message, e, n)
```